# SwiftyJSON - Unable to get transactionId from JSON String

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am using CocoaAsyncSocket to retrieve a message from a servers API that's using JSON. I am able to get the data and convert it to a printable string, what I am unable to do is retrieve a value (`transactionId`) from my attempts to parse the JSON string I already have, using SwiftyJSON. I know there are other posts that are similar to this one but none have solved my problem.

In ViewController:

```
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {

    guard let msg = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }

    var response = " "
    if msg.contains("Reset") {
        transactionID = ParseJSON().parse(message: msg)

        response = String(format: "{\"Response\":{\"transactionId\":\"%@%\",\"content\":{\"Reset\":{}}}}", transactionID)
        socket.write((response.data(using: .utf8))!, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    }

    socket?.readData(withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
}
```

ParseJSON class:

```
func parse (message: String) -> String {
    var parsedMessage = " "

    let json = JSON(parseJSON: message)
    let transactionId = json["Request"]["transactionId"].stringValue
    parsedMessage = transactionId

    print(parsedMessage)

    return parsedMessage
}
```

The result that is displayed is an empty transactionId value. Nothing prints or anything.
If you spot any errors in my code or have a better approach then please let me know!

Edit:

Here is the string I am attempting to parse:

> {"Request": {"content": {"Reset": {}}, "transactionId": "f7c4d630-552b-46d9-a37d-44450537b48d"}}

Here is my output:

> {\"Response\":{\"transactionId\":\"\",\"content\":{\"Reset\":{}}}}

Comment: Maybe not related but is the trailing `%` in the `transactionId` placeholder intended?

Comment: That was unintended, it didn't fix my problem but I will definitely remove that in case it causes further problems.

Comment: There must be something else going on because the above works fine: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/3f181810c17bba9eb982073f4983d815 Sure, you can simplify `parse` a bit, you can get rid of that extraneous `%`, I wouldn’t advise manually building JSON, etc., but bottom line, the above works fine. There is some other problem (e.g. the `msg` must not be exactly as you described it, etc.).\

Comment: So here is what I found from what you provided, if I create a variable as you did with the same string as msg then it works. What doesn't make sense is why I can copy from a printed msg and create a variable from it that works but if I use the variable msg itself then nothing is parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the code. Consider:

```
func parse(message: String) -> String {
    let json = JSON(parseJSON: message)
    return json["Request"]["transactionId"].stringValue
}

let input = """
    {"Request": {"content": {"Reset": {}}, "transactionId": "f7c4d630-552b-46d9-a37d-44450537b48d"}}
    """

let transactionID = parse(message: input)

print("transactionId:", transactionID)

let response = String(format: "{\"Response\":{\"transactionId\":\"%@\",\"content\":{\"Reset\":{}}}}", transactionID)

print("response:", response)
```

The result of the above, as you’d expect, is:

> transactionId: f7c4d630-552b-46d9-a37d-44450537b48d
>
> response: {"Response":{"transactionId":"f7c4d630-552b-46d9-a37d-44450537b48d","content":{"Reset":{}}}}

So I suspect that the input `message` is not quite what you expected. So I might suggest adding some error handling so you can diagnose precisely where it is going wrong:

```
func parse(message: String) -> String {
    let json = JSON(parseJSON: message)
    if let error = json.error {
        fatalError("JSON parsing error: \(error)")
    }

    let request = json["Request"]
    if let error = request.error {
        fatalError("request error: \(error)")
    }

    let transactionId = request["transactionId"]
    if let error = transactionId.error {
        fatalError("transactionId error: \(error)")
    }

    return transactionId.stringValue
}
```

Now, in practice, you probably wouldn’t use `fatalError`, but rather would do some graceful error handling (e.g. change `parse` such that it `throws`, then `throw` the errors encountered, if any, and then `catch` the error where you call `parse` and handle any runtime issues gracefully). But during this diagnostic process, `fatalError` is useful because it will stop your debugger at the offending line, simplifying your diagnostic process.

Bottom line, the request must not be quite in the form you expect. Note, it’s going to be very sensitive to capitalization, malformed JSON, etc. So, by looking at the errors provided by SwiftyJSON, you should be able to narrow down the issue quite quickly.

---

Below, you tell us that the `Data` is:

```
<7b225265 71756573 74223a20 7b22636f 6e74656e 74223a20 7b225265 73657422
 3a207b7d 7d2c2022 7472616e 73616374 696f6e49 64223a20 22643937 36303036
 622d3130 38302d34 3864652d 39323232 2d623139 63363663 35303164 31227d7d
 00>
```

The problem is that last byte, `0x00`. If you remove that, it works.

FWIW, when I convert that hex string back to a `Data` and run it through `JSONSerialization`, it confirms the diagnosis:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain 
>   Code=3840 "Garbage at end." 
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

You need to figure out why that `0x00` was included in the end of your payload and remove it.

Comment: Using the error handling you provided I received this Fatal Error: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Request error: wrongType** . This wrongType error means _JSON differs in type on top level_ , I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: At which line do you receive that error? Regardless, it confirms the hypothesis that the JSON is not as you described. Most likely, it is just not well-formed. Maybe you’re missing a quotation mark somewhere. Maybe a `"` is a `”`. Maybe some braces are not well balanced. It’s hard to say. We’d need to see the actual JSON, which obviously not what you have provided in your question. It may look similar, but it’s not identical. (By the way, this is why we don’t manually build JSON strings like your `String(format:)` example, to avoid precisely this sort of problem.)

Comment: I'm manually building the JSON string right now temporarily but that is not what I am trying to parse. The JSON I provided is what was read from a relay server, I did not manually build or format that. I printed what the relay server sent and copied it from the log to put on here. The relay server is reading my formatted string just fine for now, its my end attempting to read from the relay server that is not going as anticipated. What I provided was copied straight from the log that was printed from `guard let msg = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }`

Comment: Since it’s not that big, why don’t you `print(data as NSData)` and share that full hex string with us...

Comment: `<7b225265 71756573 74223a20 7b22636f 6e74656e 74223a20 7b225265 73657422 3a207b7d 7d2c2022 7472616e 73616374 696f6e49 64223a20 22643937 36303036 622d3130 38302d34 3864652d 39323232 2d623139 63363663 35303164 31227d7d 00>` The only thing different about each string is a different `transactionId`, besides that this should be accurate to the one I previously provided.

Comment: That last byte, the `0x00`, is the problem. That should not be there. And its inclusion is preventing the parsing the JSON at all. If you remove it, it works fine.

Comment: I tried removing them again but instead this time I did it in `guard let msg = String(data: data.dropLast(2), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return }` and it works as expected this time. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I would have thought `dropLast(1)` because that `00` in your hex string is only one byte. Regardless, I’m glad we solved your problem.